# Workspace Switch Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm

When you already had a project and created a new project using NPM. How we can switch by visual studio workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can switch through File -> Open Folder -> WorkspaceName.

Visual Studio Code is smart to load the code base and points the terminal.